# what is a complete undergraduate level textbook for algebra.

Tags: book-recommendation

i need a fairly elementary text(s) that includes all the topics that an undergraduate needs to know before going for a course.
i have : "higher algebra",by hall & knight.
         "higher algebra",by barnard & child.

Answer (score 0):

Well with all due respect to that book, I think Hall and Knight's Higher Algebra is rather elementary with respect to other books.
I would definitely recommend that you try "Mathematical Circles(Russian Experience)". I think this book has lots of interesting question. Check the e-book before you buy the actual book because everyone has a different taste, you may not like what I do....

Comment: i have it and i love it . thanks for responce